# 1997 Toyota Camry won't start after using Multimeter to Test Starter Wire

Tags: toyota, camry

I'll start with saying I realize I probably made a serious rookie mistake.  I took apart the driver's side interior of the car for a learning experience.  I got to the point where I removed the ignition/key core and had the car to where I could start it with a pair of pliers reaching into the core and turning the piece of metal to the on or start position.

Then, as I was testing the wires which led to the key barrel with a multimeter to see which one started the car, there was a spark.  After this, I could no longer start my car.  The spark occurred as I was checking the thick white wire.  Based on a few web searches, I think this is the 12V constant power wire, but I could be wrong.

All accessories in the car work when I turn the car to the on position.  It is only when I try to fully start the car that the accessories turn off and the engine won't start.  I don't hear any sounds.  All interior fuses look good based on visual inspection.

Any ideas?  I would love to salvage this car.  Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the fuses in the engine bay, and also look for a fusible link near the battery positive terminal. Fuses will destroy themselves to save the battery in case of an electrical short (which is what the spark was) or an overload.

Also check your battery voltage, it may just have dropped too low.